# server-client chat using WiFi and java socket programming

Tags: java, network-programming, wifi

I want to make a chat program using WiFi connection between 2 computers (ad-hoc).
I'm familiar with socket programming in java, but I can't implement this in 2 computers.
Could you help me to add WiFi network to my program?

Comment: Wifi has nothing to do with it, it's the same as if you connect the two computers directly with a Lan cable, or if you install the server in a public address. All you need is the IP address of the server (local or public) so that the client can connect, and make sure the firewall is not blocking it.

Comment: Using or not using wireless connection has no impact on your java program. Java application hosted on JVM does not have to care about used connection type.

Answer (score 0):

Each computer on your WiFi network will have an IP address. Using one computer as the host, you create your ServerSocket.
Your other computer will be the client, and can connect to the IP address of your host.

You then have your client/server over Wifi (and any other network for that matter) ready to go.

Comment: just search Google. Here is a one such example - http://www.ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html